# Python server with library socket

Tags: python

Im trying to build a python application that will be run on a specific port so that when i try to connect on that port the python application will be run.

Im guessing i have to do that with socket library but im not very sure about that.

Comment: That's not how it works. You have to run your program first, and have it start listening to a port. You can't tell the OS "listen to this port, then run this program to handle any connections to it".

Comment: that could work too but how do i do that ?

Comment: Python makes it pretty easy. Take a look here: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html

Comment: Even easier if you want to use HTTP: https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html

Comment: @Blorgbeard You can do exactly that with `xinetd` and similar super-servers.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can do this with `xinetd`. You edit `/etc/services` to give a name to your port, then add a line to `/etc/xinetd.conf` to run your server when someone connects to that service. The TCP connection will be provide to the Python script as its standard input and output.

Comment: yeah im actually using linux on virtualbox so i think this could help me THANKS

Comment: Hey, that's neat!